# Combinatorical interpretation of $\binom{15}{5} = \binom{14}{6}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was reading up on [Singmaster's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster's_conjecture) on repeated binomial coefficiencts and I read that $$\binom{15}{5} = \binom{14}{6}$$

Sure, it's possible to prove it non-combinatorically:

$$\begin{align}\binom{15}{5} &= \frac{15!}{5!10!} \\&= \frac{6\cdot15!}{10\cdot9\cdot6!8!} \\&= \frac{14!}{6!8!} \\&= \binom{14}{6}\end{align}$$

However, I was thinking: is it possible to come up with a combinatorical argument that proves the equality of the two?

Comment: No, it's coincidence. Otherwise more examples like this should be known

Comment: Since $ \ 3003 \ = \ 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \ $ , it seems more like this is a case of having the right "window" of prime factor cancellations between the numerators and denominators (since the number also turns up as $ \ \binom{78}{2} \ $ ) .  There isn't any evident argument for why choosing five items from fifteen without replacement _ought to_ be the same as choosing six out of fourteen.